# Getting a hash from an arbitrary structure instance

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-set

Is it possible to get a hash from an arbitrary instance with std::hash instead of crc_mem?

```
static uint32_t crc_table[16] = {
    0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
    0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
    0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};

unsigned long crc_update(unsigned long crc, byte data) {
    byte tbl_idx;
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (0 * 4));
    crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);
    tbl_idx = crc ^ (data >> (1 * 4));
    crc = crc_table[tbl_idx & 0x0f] ^ (crc >> 4);
    return crc;
}

unsigned long crc_mem(char* s, int n) {
    unsigned long crc = ~0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        crc = crc_update(crc, s[i]);
    }
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}

size_t my_struct::GetChecksum() const {
    return crc_mem((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
}
```

I want to use this hash for unordered_map like so std::unordered_map <my_struct, int> map1;

Comment: You can add specializations to `std::hash` for your own types.

Comment: _"..arbitrary structure instance..."_ - no because any arbitrary hashing function would try and hash the padding data (as C++ does not have reflection).  As padding is undefined two otherwise identical structures could produce different hashes.  Boost has some helper functions for combining hashes and you can use these to combine the hashes of each member of the structure that make up it's identity.